# SQL Query taking too long. How to make my queries more efficient? Creating smaller tables from database tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to make a simple Query where I gather a lot of information about one order from many different tables.

This is my code (it's just mostly select statements):

```
Select 

o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number as Shopify_Num,
o.Control_Number, 

o.Date_Entered as AMT_Timestamp,

case when p.PickTicket_Number is null then i.PickTicket_Number else p.PickTicket_Number end PickTicket_Number,

i.Invoice_Number,

CASE WHEN  o.Order_Status=30 THEN 'CANCELED' 
WHEN  o.Order_Status=45 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
WHEN  o.Order_Status=10 THEN 'NORMAL' 
WHEN  o.Order_Status=20 THEN 'NORMAL' 
END Order_Status, 

od.Odet_Line_Number,
od.Item_Number,
st.Description,
od.Color_Code,
c.Color_Description,

o.Order_Value as Total_Price_Before_Discount, 
od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered as Line_Price_Before_Discount, 
od.Discount_Value, 
od.Discount_Percentage, 
od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value as Line_Price_After_Discount,

SUM(od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value) OVER(PARTITION BY o.control_number) AS Total_Price_After_Discount,

od.Tax_Value, od.Tax_Percentage,

od.Quantity_Ordered,
od.Quantity_Allocated,
od.Quantity_Invoiced,

CASE WHEN  od.Line_Status=90 THEN 'ALLOCATED'
WHEN  od.Line_Status=80 THEN 'CANCELED' 
WHEN  od.Line_Status=70 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
WHEN  od.Line_Status=50 THEN 'NORMAL' 
END Line_Status,

SUM(od.Freight_Charges) OVER(PARTITION BY o.control_number) AS Shipping_Cost_To_Customer,

case When sh.packslip is not null then 'SHIPPED & UPLOADED' ELSE z.status END Accellos_Status,
sh.Date_modfy Accellos_Timestamp, 

o.Warehouse_Code,
b.UPS_Tracking_Number AMT_Tracking_Number, 
sm.TRACKTRACE Accellos_Tracking_Number, 
sh.SHIP_NAME ,
sh.SHIP_ADD1 ,
sh.SHIP_ADD2 ,
sh.SHIP_CITY ,
sh.SHIP_PROV ,
sh.SHIP_ZIP,
o.Ship_Via_Code, 
sv.Description_1 as Ship_Descrp,
sh.SHIP_VIA,
sh.SHIP_SERVC,
sh.SERVICE,
sh.SHIP_NUM,
sh.COST_SHIP,
sh.SHIP_WGHT

from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders o (nolock)
join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Detail od (nolock) on o.Company_Code=od.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=od.Division_Code and o.Control_Number=od.Control_Number
left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P (nolock) on o.Company_Code=p.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=p.Division_Code and o.Control_Number=p.Control_Number
left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices i (nolock) on o.Company_Code=i.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=i.Division_Code and o.Control_Number=i.Control_Number
left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].box b (nolock) on o.Company_Code=b.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=b.Division_Code and i.PickTicket_Number=b.PickTicket_Number

left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Color c (nolock) on od.Color_Code = c.Color_Code
left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style st (nolock) on o.Company_Code=st.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=st.Division_Code and od.item_number=st.item_number and c.color_code = st.color_code 
left join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Ship_Via_File sv (nolock) on o.ship_via_code = sv.ship_via_code

left join pickhead ph (nolock) on p.PickTicket_Number=ph.packslip
left join Z_Status z on ph.PROCSTEP=z.procstep
left join SHIPHIST sh (nolock) on case when p.PickTicket_Number is null then i.PickTicket_Number else p.PickTicket_Number end=sh.packslip

left join SHIPMSTR2 sm (nolock) on case when p.PickTicket_Number is null then i.PickTicket_Number else p.PickTicket_Number end=sm.packslip

where LTRIM(RTRIM(o.Company_Code))+LTRIM(RTRIM(o.Division_Code))='03001'  and o.Customer_Number='ecom2x'
and o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number='3112480'
```

This query is taking about 10 seconds to run. Is there any way to make it more efficient? It's already pretty barebones. I'm assuming I should try to minimize any redundant tables first since these tables I'm joining are pretty large. Is there anything I can do if I need all the tables I chose? A lot of these table I'm joining have dozens of columns when I'm joining them for just one specific column out of the whole table. Does that change anything?

So I could create a bunch of new tables from my database tables, selecting for only the columns I need. Then I can use those tables instead. I tried to do something like that but it only made the query run never-ending (or atleast over a minute).

This is what I tried:

I think it fails because I essentially told it to recreate this huge table which takes a lot of time.

```
SELECT Company_Code, Division_Code, Control_Number, Customer_Purchase_Order_Number, 
       Date_Entered, Order_Status, Order_Value, 
       Warehouse_Code, Ship_Via_Code 
       into #o from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders OT (nolock)

SELECT Company_Code, Division_Code, Control_Number, Odet_Line_Number, 
       Item_Number, Color_Code, Price, 
       Discount_Value, Discount_Percentage, Tax_Value, Tax_Percentage,
       Quantity_Ordered, Quantity_Allocated, Quantity_Invoiced, Line_Status, Freight_Charges 
       into #od from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Detail ODT (nolock) 
.
.
.
from #o (nolock)
join #od (nolock) on o.Company_Code=od.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=od.Division_Code and o.Control_Number=od.Control_Number
left join #p (nolock) on o.Company_Code=p.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=p.Division_Code and o.Control_Number=p.Control_Number
.
.
.
```

Does anyone know how to speed this code up/ make it more efficient in general?

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) and give us your query plan. and NOLOCK will give you dirty reads, or can...[read up on that here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: Is there a description field/table to avoid using those CASE statements?

Comment: First I would propones to rewrite sentence  where LTRIM(RTRIM(o.Company_Code))+LTRIM(RTRIM(o.Division_Code))='03001' yo eliminate the +

Comment: Also, try using sub-queries to retrieve data from bigger tables.  See if that helps!

Comment: After a closer look, it seems like me joining this table

      (left join SHIPMSTR2 sm (nolock) on case when p.PickTicket_Number is null then i.PickTicket_Number else p.PickTicket_Number end=sm.packslip)


is causing the query to go from 3 seconds to 10 seconds or more. This is a very large table but I only need like two columns from it. What is the best way to optimize for this?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the foreign key fields.